# Any way to include a function as message with mosquitto in python?

Tags: python, database, mqtt, sensors, mosquitto

```
import dweepy
import os

_=os.system("clear")


myThing = "4400D_sensor" #Add value: add your dweet thing name


print("getting latest dweet...")
latest_dweet = dweepy.get_latest_dweet_for(myThing) #get latest dweet
latest_created = latest_dweet[0]["created"]  #put the created value of the lastest dweet into a variable
latest_content = latest_dweet[0]["content"]
print("Latest dweet time:", latest_created)
print("Latest dweet content:", latest_content)
print("Latest dweet JSON")
print(latest_dweet)
print()
os.system('mosquitto_pub -d -h 172.19.0.12 -t cisco/iots/user -m "testing"')
```

The above is my current code and I am trying to figure out a way to replace the string "testing" with my latest_dweet variable so I can send a different message each time instead of hardcoding it. Any idea how I can do that?

I am trying to play around with that line where I want to achieve my goal however right now I am still unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Don't!

Go look at the Paho Python library to send MQTT messages directly from the python code rather than shelling out to `mosquitto_pub`

https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/

Comment: so after changing to paho, i am currently using this line "publish.single("cisco/iots/user", "test", hostname="172.19.0.12") Any idea how I can change the string of "Test" to a variable name ?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: hmm seems like i got it figured out